How to add a row which displays totals for all the value columns in Pivot Table Google Sheets

Google Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZY3jhSvfwC6ZU44g16l8QCuqDsgirRi93L78aQV6Tk/edit?usp=sharing
I want rows which displays totals for all "STYLE NO. / COL" column.
For ex: (See the highlighted cells)
For 905 / 35
26 total: 1
28 total: 2
30 total: 2
32 total: 2
34 total: 0
so on

If its for all STYLE NO. / COL, then tickmark the Show totals for Dealer in Pivot Table Editor

That gives me my solution! but how does it make sense? can you please explain?
